# Drive push messages - spammed by notifications

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-api-nodejs-client

I am currently developing system synchronizing files between Google Drive and external storage. I am trying to process push notifications. I was already able to register for them and receive them. After receiving each notification, I acquire list of changes using proper endpoint and try to get a new version of file if necessary, so the flow is like that:

1. Subscribe to notifications using `changes.watch`
2. Receive some push message with url to changes
3. Use API with provided query to get changes on `changes.list` endpoint
4. Filter items that changed after particular moment
5. Get content of file and transfer it to another service

It seems that after initial notify message, Google starts spamming a new one, always after getting file. I suspect that the action of getting file content is changing some timestamp on file and therefore - its content is changed.

Is it possible not to modify file in any way when getting its content?

**EDIT:**

It seems that this behaviour concerns files.export endpoint as well - Exporting Google Doc as PDF leads to notifications spam too. Commenting out export part in a code stops them from coming.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting spammed since [Changes: watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch) listens more to changes made by a user, not the file itself.

What you need to use in this scenario is [Files: watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/watch). It subscribes you to listen to changes to the file itself.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the reason for these updates is getting the files. I checked notification messages - each describes exactly the same change and if I comment out only file getting part - I get only one notification after each file change, as expected.
Watching for changes is viable solution, but getting the file is a problematic part.